# equivalency weak and strong form

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to show that 
if u is smooth enough and $$u\in V, \int_\Omega k \nabla u.\nabla v=\int_\Omega fv ~~~for ~all~v\in V$$
that $$V=\{{v\in H^1(\Omega):v=0 ~on ~\Gamma_1}\}$$
then $u$ is  the solution for the PDE:
$$-\nabla (k.\nabla u) =f ~in ~\Omega$$
$$u=0~on~\Gamma_1$$
$$ k~\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0~on~\Gamma_2$$where $k$ is positive.
I used Green identity so:
$$\int_{\Gamma_2}k\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}v-\int_{\Omega}\nabla (k.\nabla u)v=\int_{\Omega}fv$$
Now I don't know how to continue. Please hint me

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look for [the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations), in particular the du Bois-Reymond lemma. Using this, you should show that the PDE is satisfied in $\Omega$. Then you could go for the boundary condition.